# I've created a nodeJS app on heroku with github automatic deployment. now I want to make that repository private,initially it was public

Tags: github, heroku, deployment

can someone help me with this. my MongoDB connection string is public which is a bit risky. Now I want to make that Repo private without changing anything to my Heroku nodeJS app.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a module with URLs and such. Then import that into your code, and make sure that said module is included in `.gitignore` such that it won't be included in the repo. I believe this way is the least intrusive solution to your existing setup.